# Is there a name for such graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, terminology

$G$ is constructed in the following way:

Take a cycle and attach two paths at two different vertices of the cycle. Is there a terminology for such graphs? What are they called?

Note: If only one path is attached, it is known as $Tadpole$ graph.

Comment: No, [lollipop graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LollipopGraph.html) is the graph obtained by joining a complete graph $K_m$ to a path graph $P_n$ with a bridge.

Comment: [Tadpole graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TadpoleGraph.html) is what you meant for one path attached.

Comment: You are right. I edited the question.